# Como obter o tipo de codificação de um arquivo?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, codificação-de-caracteres

Segue código:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText($@"{pathname}", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Tenho vários arquivos txt com condificação diferente. Porque aqui não mostra caracteres especial, por causa codificação diferente.

Antes de executar a linha `File.ReadAllText`, como faço para obter o tipo de arquivo?

Exemplo: ANSI, UNICODE, UTF-8, ETC...

Algo parecido assim:

```
if (pathname == Encoding.ASCII)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText($@"{pathname}", Encoding.ASCII);
}
else if (pathname == Encoding.UTF8)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText($@"{pathname}", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que ler o arquivo para saber então provavelmente compensa ler de outra forma. Usando o `StreamReader` e ler pelo menos uma parte pode descobrir com a propriedade [`CurrentEncoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader_CurrentEncoding). Mas dizem que ela não é confiável.

Se tiver dificuldades com ela pode tentar usar uma biblioteca como a [chardetsharp](https://github.com/superstrom/chardetsharp), [UDE](https://github.com/errepi/ude), [NCharDet](https://github.com/ziyunhx/thrinax/tree/master/NChardet), [Architect Shack](http://architectshack.com/TextFileEncodingDetector.ashx). Não as conheço e não sei o quanto são confiáveis.

Tem respostas no SO com códigos que tentam fazer o trabalho: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853721/221800), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464728/221800) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283954/221800).

Se quiser entender melhor sobre o [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Sempre terá casos que pode detectar errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tem como saber se o detectado der errado ? Vixi me ferrou, vou tentar com biblioteca que tu me indicou.

Comment: Não de forma confiável, inclusive porque o texto pode estar em uma codificação mal formada. Confiável só será se puder garantir que o arquivo nunca está corrompido e ter um cabeçalho no arquivo que indique a codificação. Eventualmente é isto o que você obterá em algumas codificações padrões. Se souber que só terá duas ou três codificações diferente e quais são ajuda um pouco porque você pode limitar as escolhas. Tem codificações que podem ser ambíguas.

Comment: Entendo você sabe me dizer qual é forma mais segura de saber qual o tipo de codificação?

Comment: Uma dessas aí mesmo, mas não sei qual. Aí pode refinar manualmente para dar menos erro. Mas testa porque pode ser que vá bem com o padrão que você tem.

Comment: Entendo, a melhor biblioteca (na minha opinião) é UDE. Porque ele fala o tipo da codificação e o nível da CONFIANÇA de arquivo que retorna `float`. É o que você escreveu no comentário: `o texto pode estar em uma codificação mal formada`.

Comment: Bora apagar comentário ?